# html table td right allignment for amount columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I am using the html table for displaying the records and also i am having amount column in records, so i need to align that particular td in right allignment and all other td in left alignment. My table `width=100%`, the columns are equally divided. the right alligned values are not straight to the header.

```css
.right-frame-cell-3 {
    height: 270px;
}
.right-frame-cell-3 .tcont {
    height: 226px;
    overflow: auto;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent
}
.right-frame-cell-3 .cell-header {
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
table thead th {
    text-align: left;
}
.right-frame-cell-3 table td:nth-child(5) {
    text-align: right;
}
table.table-cell3 thead th {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
table.table-cell3 td {
    text-align: left;
    color: #2196F3;
}
table.table-cell3 thead tr th {
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
table.table-cell3 thead tr th div {
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
    line-height: normal;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame-cell right-frame-cell-3 ui-summ1" >
    <div class="cell-header">
        <span>Time Detail From </span><span class="from_date" style="margin-left:10px;">07-Sep-16</span><span style="margin-left:10px;"> to </span><span class="to_date" style="margin-left:10px;">07-Sep-16</span>
        <span style="margin-left:25%;color:black;font-weight:bold;">TIME</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tcont-wrap" style="overflow:hidden;position:relative;">
        <div class="tcont">
            <table class="table-cell3" width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Date
                            <div>Date</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Client Code
                            <div>Client Code</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Work Description
                            <div>Work Description</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Location
                            <div>Location</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Duration
                            <div>Duration</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Delete
                            <div>Delete</div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>07-Sep-16</td>
                    <td>NXS</td>
                    <td>Reset Password and worked on....</td>
                    <td>O</td>
                    <td>2.5</td>
                    <td>Delete</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now My Output is

[image]

now i want to align the fifth column Duration (td) in right alignment and also straight to the header. that means i specify whitespace to be removed or anything

Anyone please give me the solutions and suggestion ?

Awaiting Response ? *Thanks in Advance*

Comment: It seems the snippet provided by you is working fine. where is issue?

Comment: yes its working on small resolution sizes when its comes to normal size resolution problem occures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Width on `th` for `Duration`  `80px`

```css
.right-frame-cell-3 {
    height: 270px;
}
.right-frame-cell-3 .tcont {
    height: 226px;
    overflow: auto;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent
}
.right-frame-cell-3 .cell-header {
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
table thead th {
    text-align: left;
}
.right-frame-cell-3 table td:nth-child(5) {
    text-align: right;
}
table.table-cell3 thead th {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
table.table-cell3 td {
    text-align: left;
    color: #2196F3;
}
table.table-cell3 thead tr th {
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
table.table-cell3 thead tr th div {
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
    line-height: normal;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame-cell right-frame-cell-3 ui-summ1" >
    <div class="cell-header">
        <span>Time Detail From </span><span class="from_date" style="margin-left:10px;">07-Sep-16</span><span style="margin-left:10px;"> to </span><span class="to_date" style="margin-left:10px;">07-Sep-16</span>
        <span style="margin-left:25%;color:black;font-weight:bold;">TIME</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tcont-wrap" style="overflow:hidden;position:relative;">
        <div class="tcont">
            <table class="table-cell3" width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Date
                            <div>Date</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Client Code
                            <div>Client Code</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Work Description
                            <div>Work Description</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Location
                            <div>Location</div>
                        </th>
                        <th width="80">
                            Duration
                            <div>Duration</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Delete
                            <div>Delete</div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>07-Sep-16</td>
                    <td>NXS</td>
                    <td>Reset Password and worked on....</td>
                    <td>O</td>
                    <td>2.5</td>
                    <td>Delete</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: all my code is generated ? Not hard code value in "" is it possible ? with hard coding that style="width:80px"

Comment: i've taken your idea and dynamically applying the width from JQUERY. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
.right-frame-cell-3 {
    height: 270px;
}
.right-frame-cell-3 .tcont {
    height: 226px;
    overflow: auto;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent
}
.right-frame-cell-3 .cell-header {
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
table thead th {
    text-align: left;
}
.right-frame-cell-3 table td:nth-child(5) {
    text-align: right;
}
table.table-cell3 thead th {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
table.table-cell3 td {
    text-align: left;
    color: #2196F3;
}
table.table-cell3 thead tr th {
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
table.table-cell3 thead tr th div {
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
    line-height: normal;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    top: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="frame-cell right-frame-cell-3 ui-summ1" >
    <div class="cell-header">
        <span>Time Detail From </span><span class="from_date" style="margin-left:10px;">07-Sep-16</span><span style="margin-left:10px;"> to </span><span class="to_date" style="margin-left:10px;">07-Sep-16</span>
        <span style="margin-left:25%;color:black;font-weight:bold;">TIME</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tcont-wrap" style="overflow:hidden;position:relative;">
        <div class="tcont">
            <table class="table-cell3" width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Date
                            <div>Date</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Client Code
                            <div>Client Code</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Work Description
                            <div>Work Description</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Location
                            <div>Location</div>
                        </th>
                        <th >
                            Duration
                            <div>Duration</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Delete
                            <div>Delete</div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>07-Sep-16</td>
                    <td>NXS</td>
                    <td>Reset Password and worked on....</td>
                    <td>O</td>
                    <td>2.5</td>
                    <td>Delete</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But i need that column heading in left alignment only

Comment: Sure, I have edited the above code please have a look

Comment: yes ! but i need the heading in left alignment only, **Duration** Field always present left only

Answer (score 0):

the fiddle shows the Duration Div on the right because the text-alignment on the 5th child is right. i dont know why but try to force it:

```
table.table-cell3 thead tr th div {
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
    line-height: normal;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: left !important;     <----------
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    top: 0;
}
```